# Multiple Clicks Before Button Reacts

Tags: button

I have 3 areas set up to act like buttons in my application, they work, but for some reason I have to click it multiple times before it does what it's supposed to do. Is this because it's checking if the user has click in that specific area?

(I'm using LWJGL/Slick2D)

```
public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)throws SlickException {

        int xpos = Mouse.getX();
        int ypos = Mouse.getY();

        //Play Game Button
        if((xpos > 276 && xpos < 556 ) && (ypos > 230 && ypos < 270)) {
            if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
                sbg.enterState(1);
                click = new Sound("res/click.wav");
                click.play();
                TOW = new Music("res/TownOfWishes.ogg");
                TOW.loop();
                TOW.setVolume(0.1f);
            }
        }

        //Exit Game Button
        if((xpos > 276 && xpos < 556 ) && (ypos > 154 && ypos < 195)) {
            if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
                click = new Sound("res/click.wav");
                click.play();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        //Settings Game Button
        if((xpos > 276 && xpos < 556 ) && (ypos > 80 && ypos < 121)) {
            if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
                click = new Sound("res/click.wav");
                click.stop();
                sbg.enterState(2);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you specify "multiple times"? Is it always the same number of times?

Comment: I'd suggest editing your post to add a tag for the appropriate language. I'm guessing it's c#, but I'm not sure enough to edit it myself.

Comment: I usually have to click the button 2-3 times to get it to function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good but your problem could be your coordinate system(orthographic matrix setup)  or your actual calculation itself. Try double checking your math.

Comment: I found out that when I export the project, the problem does not exist. Just only when running the project in Eclipse. Thanks for your help though!